# ASP.net incorrect file path App_data- works only on localhost

Tags: asp.net, path

I have got a excel sheet (.xls) in my `app_data folder` and when I access the website on IE the path is shown as:
`c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\Book2.xls`

however when I access on the localhost it is shown as:
`\\webserver\webserver\project\App_Data\Book1.xls` (which is the correct path)

The correct path is only shown on the localhost. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Where are you getting those paths from? What is "showing the path as..."? IIS? and what do you mean by accessing on IE one way, but access "on the localhost" the other? Those comparisons make no sense.

Comment: I am accessing the site through the server directly..localhost is used for debugging the website.

Comment: Where are you getting those paths from?

Comment: Its the location of the app_data on my solution.

Comment: **What** is telling you those two different paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Both of them are correct but are different - and none of this is correct for use on web.**

When you access it with IE as `c:\` then the IE actually is not a browser any more but a **file manager**.

When you access it with IE as `\\webserver\`  then IE actually work as **network browsers**. In a local network this can work, but the connection is done from MS network access layer and not from the web iis.

In both cases IE is not acting as web browser. IE have advertised that is together all this 3, file browser, network browser and web browser (and maybe photo browser and other).

Because you use IE not means that behind the IE use the same code for all cases. Not, its not, IE use different access method for the 3 cases.

### Note

None of this are correct for the web !. And actually you can not share data on the app_data directory because is a protected directory from asp.net.

a correct directory for the web is like `http://www.yoursite.com/directory/book.xls` where the book.xls is under the `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\directory\`

Comment: But the same code works on another website I made. I dont understand why its changing it to the inetpub one

Comment: @kjt15 Its maybe works because you testing it on local computer or on local network. None of this pass IIS and asp.net.

Comment: Actually I have another website working on the local network. How can i get it to run on the local network. When I debug it it works!...

Comment: @kjt15 Please take some time and read for the network connection on windows, and separate in your mine from IIS and http protocol. There are different thinks.

Comment: I looked at the url my other website is using and it is actually using the inetpub\wwwroot url aswell! This means I need to find out why one works and the other doesnt. But at least I know its using the right url, but not why it doesnt work..